# Grepl, str_match and copy in if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have something like that:

```
ID

<</>something>[TMOD-106]<</>something></>

<</>something>[TMOD-107]<</>something></>

REQ_SYS_100

REQ_SYS_101
```

And I would like to have in the next column something like that:

```
ID.2
[TMOD-106]

[TMOD-107]

REQ_SYS_100

REQ_SYS_101
```

So if there are signs "//" I won't need only the ID between them, and if there are not just copy it. 
I have tried something like that:

```
if grepl "REQ" data$ID {
then
  data$col2 <- data$ID 
else 
  str_match(data$ID, ">(.*?)<") 
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Are you processing HTML content?

Comment: What is the `<something>`?  Can you show us real data instead?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to phrase this would be to try to extract a term in brackets, otherwise just take the entire original input:

```
df$ID.2 <- sub(".*(\\[.*?\\]).*", "\\1", df$ID)
df$ID.2

         ID.2
1 [TMOD-106]
2 [TMOD-107]
3 REQ_SYS_100
4 REQ_SYS_101
```

### Demo

The above approach works, at least for the data you showed us, because the behavior of `sub` is that it returns the original input if a match cannot be made.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfect. But now I find another case, where I have something like that: <something>TMOD-1010<something>  Maybe do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: I'm not editing anything until you show us your actual data.

Comment: This is my actual data:   <span style="font-weight: bold;">SPRC-TS-01</span>    or     <span style="font-weight: bold;">[SPRC-TS-01]</span>    or just    REQ_SYS_1020

Comment: I have already solved my problem, however thank you once again.